# Under which circumstances can the class number of a quadratic form not degenerate into the class number of imaginary quadratic fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

The number of primitive reduced forms with discriminant $D< 0$ is called the class number of discriminant $D$. We denote it by $h_f(D)$.

Write down a Delta symbol

$$
\Delta(D)=\begin{cases}
\operatorname{sqfr}(D)&\operatorname{sqfr}(D)\equiv1\pmod{4}\\
4\operatorname{sqfr}(D)&\operatorname{sqfr}(D)\not\equiv1\pmod{4}\\
\end{cases}$$

where the square-free part of the integer $n$ is represented by $\operatorname{sqfr}(n)$.

The class number of the imaginary quadratic field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ is denoted as $h(D)$, where $D$ is a negative integer, then

$$h(D)=h(\Delta(D))=h_f(\Delta(D))\qquad\,D<0$$

The class number of the imaginary quadratic field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d_K})$ is a denoted as $h(d_K)$, where $d_K$ is fundamental discriminant, and its definition refers to the link [1], then

$$h(d_K)=h(\Delta(d_K))=h_f(\Delta(d_K))=h_f(d_K)\qquad\,d_K\in\mathrm{FD}_K$$

I want to ask, is this not missing some situations?
In other words, when the negative integer $D$ is not a fundamental discriminant, **is there a strict inequality** in class numbers?

This fact seems to explain why there are more quadratic forms with class number equal to one than quadratic fields with class number equal to one.

\begin{align*}
h_f(d) = 1 &\Leftrightarrow d = −3, −4, −7, −8, −11, −12, −16,\\
&\qquad\quad\>\>−19, −27, −28, −43, −67, −163;\\
h(d_K) = 1 &\Leftrightarrow d_K = −3, −4, −7, −8, −11,\\
&\qquad\qquad−19, −43, −67, −163.\\
\end{align*}

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_discriminant

Comment: I think the correspondence between equivalence classes of quadratic forms with a certain discriminant and elements of the ideal class group of a certain ring works even for orders in imaginary quadratic fields, not just the ring of integers. It's possible that this is described in Fröhlich/Taylor, but I can't check right now.